# cannot deploy spring web application using indigo+m2e+wtp

Tags: eclipse, spring, classnotfoundexception, m2e, m2e-wtp

When deploying spring MVC application I am having `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener`

Details:
 - eclipse Indigo Service Release 2 (Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers)
 - "m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse"
 - "m2e-wtp - Maven Integration for WTP"
I confirm that my web project has "maven dependencies" added in deployment assembly. I tried to do some cleanup like "update project configuration", "maven clean install" ... but issue is still there, any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think there was a bug at some point in the m2e-wtp plugin.  I did an update to the latest version (Help->Check for updates) and this problem went away for me.